# Finding all possible outcomes of two dice using Outer in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, outer-join

I am just getting started with Wolfram Mathematica 9, and am trying to learn how to use the Outer function. I have a problem where I want to generate a list containing all possible outcomes from rolling two dice. I have the following list to start with.

`numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }`

The list I want to generate should be on the following form.

`{ { 1, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 1, 3 }, ..., { 6, 6 } }`

I have tried things like

`Outer[Times, numbers, numbers]`

to no avail. How do I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is `Tuples[numbers, 2]` any use?

Comment: `Outer[List, numbers, numbers]` is what I was looking for. Thank you both!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark will you consider submitting your comment as an Answer for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick to `Outer` try `Outer[List,numbers,numbers]`.

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to, there is another way to do this. Consider
Subsets[Range[1, 6], {2}]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Join`  by  `Outer[{#1}~Join~{#2},numbers,numbers]`.